# Crash in Qt::show()

Tags: qt, qt4

I have written code on showing a popup dialog(QDialog), on hover of a QToolButton. I'm getting the following stack-trace repeatedly. Is this expected?

```
0   QtGui                           0x0642d209 QWindow::windowState() const + 9
1   libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0b10e0f4 0xb0fe000 + 65780
2   QtGui                           0x0642c0e0 QWindow::setVisible(bool) + 736
3   QtWidgets                       0x0693524b QWidgetPrivate::show_sys() + 907
4   QtWidgets                       0x06916795 QWidgetPrivate::show_helper() + 469
5   QtWidgets                       0x069172e8 QWidget::setVisible(bool) + 1128
6   QtWidgets                       0x06ad6573 QDialog::setVisible(bool) + 243
7   QtWidgets                       0x06916544 QWidget::show() + 180
```

Is this a known stack trace? I made sure that I'm using a shared_ptr and it is not null at any case. And there are no two popups visible at the same time.

Adding invocation code:

```
fDialog.reset(new kcqt::QtPopupWidget(kcqt::QtPopupArrow::eArrowEast, false));
fDialog->setStyleSheet(fIPopupDialog);
fDialog->update();
//Orient Popup south-west when it does not lie in the visible window
if((parentGlobalLocation.y()+fBookElementsDialog->height()/2)>aMain->height())
{
    fDialog->setGeometry(parentGlobalLocation.x()-dialogSize.width(),parentGlobalLocation.y()-dialogSize.height()+45, dialogSize.width(), dialogSize.height());
    fDialog->updateGeometry();
    fDialog->updateArrowOrientation(kcqt::QtPopupArrow::eArrowSouthEast_East);
    fDialog->update();
    fDialog->show();
    return;
}
```

It is crashing in `Qt::Show()`

Comment: Kindly post your code here to better understand your issue.

Comment: Azeem, I have updated the code in the description.

Comment: What your debugger says when it crasher? Which row? Data are consistent? Pointers are ok?

Comment: What is `fDialog`?